# The Heading2 style in ModernUI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, modern-ui

We're working with the ModernUI framework for our WPF apps. I've come across a style called Heading2, but I cannot find it anywhere in our code, either the XAML or the C# code. Is Heading2 defined somewhere in ModernUI?

Comment: It's not in your code, and you can't find it anywhere else? Would this question be more suitable for [another Stack Exchange site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com)? Is the answer "what have I got in my pocket?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can reference it in your code as below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/TextBlock.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Text="Hello Heading2!" Style="{StaticResource Heading2}"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="No Heading..."></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]